# Deployment order in Jboss 5

Tags: jboss

In JBoss 4, you could set the order that objects were deployed (`.jar`, `.war`, `.sar`, etc...) in the file: `conf/xmdesc/org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer-xmbean.xml`.

I have been unable to find the similar configuration in JBoss 5.

Any ideas how to adjust this? We have a `.sar` that needs to be deployed after all of our `.jar`s and Im' not sure how to make that happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the new corresponding [link](http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/jboss-howto/42-jboss-config/206-how-to-force-jboss-to-deploy-the-ejb-first-in-an-ear-.html)

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem (or rather a friend did):

http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/jboss-howto/42-jboss-config/206-how-to-force-jboss-to-deploy-the-ejb-first-in-an-ear-.html

Answer (score 2):

mastertheboss.com has changed its URI strategy (not cool); here is the new one: http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/jboss-howto/42-jboss-config/206-how-to-force-jboss-to-deploy-the-ejb-first-in-an-ear-.html

[link updated]

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sorry (being owner of the MTB site) of the issues caused by the new URLs. Since lots of new topics and frameworks have been added to the site, I had to re-engineer the site URLs, writing a few hundreds 301 redirects to keep compatibility with ealier URLs. Unfortunately it seems some URLs are still wrong and trying to fix them all using Google Analytics. Sorry for the inconvenience.