# war deployment sequence under ear

Tags: maven, war, ear

I'm new to this concept.

I'm having two `wars` under **ear**. `War-1` is consisitng of one servlet with load on startup parameter, which I want to deploy first and after this is completed, `War-2` should be deployed.How this can be done?

I'm using `maven` with `Jboss7.1.1.Final`.

Please help

Comment: The [Deployment order in Jboss 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267678/deployment-order-in-jboss-5) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use modules. Assuming your project looks like this :

- Ear (pom.xml)

  - War-1
  - War-2

Add pom files in War-1 and War-2 directories. The pom file in ear directory will be the parent, where you declare modules to be processed :

```xml
<modules>
    <module>War-1</module>
    <module>War-2</module>
</modules>
```

Maven will look-up for poms in War-1 and War-2 directories. Create a new pom in each one :

- Ear (pom.xml)

  - War-1 (pom.xml)
  - War-2 (pom.xml)

There, an abstract of pom.xml in each sub-module. Your have to declare the parent :

```xml
<parent>
    <artifactId>yourArtifact</artifactId>
    <groupId>yourGroup</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<!-- Name your package as you like -->
<groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
<artifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}-War1</artifactId>
<name>${project.parent.artifactId}-War1</name>
<description>
    War of project ${project.parent.artifactId}
</description>

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Is that what you were looking for ? You will find more information on modules at http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

@+